# Show Base64 file as PNG

Tags: html, base64

Images are captured by one part of our system as PNG files and then base64 encoded and stored on Amazon S3.  We'd like to display these images in HTML emails that are sent and the obvious issue is that they are base64 encoded.

Linking directly to the object doesn't work, and it seems that using an image tag such as the following does not display the image in any email client I've tried (Gmail, Live/outlook.com, Outlook, Apple Mail):

```
<img src="data:image/png;charset=utf-8;base64,http://url/filename" />
```

Any ideas?  I don't have control over the fact that the objects are written as Base64.  I could read/download the objects ahead of time but cannot write to the file system, so any real-time conversion would need to be done in memory.  Hoping for a solution that leverages HTML.  This is not a background image - it will be in the body itself.

Edit:
I've also tried just putting the base64 string in place of the URL - which works in some cases, but some email clients (like Gmail) won't display it - which is why I'm preferring a URL-based solution.